# Как правильно прикрутить том к контейнеру docker?

Tags: docker

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно прикрутить том к новому контейнеру docker. Создавал тестовый контейнер с DNS сервером. И к нему хотел сделать так сказать папку хранения данных с настройками ну и если к примеру если бы я обновлял бы данные DNS то они бы тоде сохранялись бы. Попробую расписать всё как я делал и возможно допустил ошибку:

***Создал images***

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y bind9

COPY named.conf.options named.conf.local /etc/bind/
COPY db.example.com /etc/bind/zones/

CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-g", "-c", "/etc/bind/named.conf", "-u", "bind"]

EXPOSE 53/tcp
EXPOSE 53/udp
EXPOSE 953/tcp
```

Далее пытаюсь запустить новый контейнер с этим images

```
docker run -v /var/test/bind:/etc/bind --name test1 -it -p 53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp -p 127.0.0.1:953:953/tcp t1:t1
```

Запускал сначала контейнер в флагом -d но контейнер после создания сразу останавливался. Решил запустить с флагами -it и вот что я в ответ получил

```
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 starting BIND 9.18.18-0ubuntu2-Ubuntu (Extended Support Version) <id:>
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 running on Linux x86_64 6.5.0-14-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Nov 14 14:59:49 UTC 2023
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 built with  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-option-checking' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--runstatedir=/run' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--with-python=python3' '--localstatedir=/' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--with-gost=no' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=yes' '--with-libidn2' '--with-json-c' '--with-lmdb=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-maxminddb' '--with-atf=no' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-rrl' '--enable-filter-aaaa' '--disable-native-pkcs11' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/bind9-UHPUkp/bind9-9.18.18=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fcf-protection -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/bind9-UHPUkp/bind9-9.18.18=/usr/src/bind9-1:9.18.18-0ubuntu2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -DNO_VERSION_DATE -DDIG_SIGCHASE' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 running as: named -g -c /etc/bind/named.conf -u bind
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 compiled by GCC 13.2.0
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 compiled with OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.10 1 Aug 2023
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 linked to OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.10 1 Aug 2023
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 compiled with libuv version: 1.44.2
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 linked to libuv version: 1.44.2
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 compiled with libxml2 version: 2.9.14
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 linked to libxml2 version: 20914
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 compiled with json-c version: 0.17
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 linked to json-c version: 0.17
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 compiled with zlib version: 1.2.13
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 linked to zlib version: 1.2.13
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 ----------------------------------------------------
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit 
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are 
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 available at https://www.isc.org/support
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 ----------------------------------------------------
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 found 4 CPUs, using 4 worker threads
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.992 using 4 UDP listeners per interface
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.996 DNSSEC algorithms: RSASHA1 NSEC3RSASHA1 RSASHA256 RSASHA512 ECDSAP256SHA256 ECDSAP384SHA384 ED25519 ED448
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.996 DS algorithms: SHA-1 SHA-256 SHA-384
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.996 HMAC algorithms: HMAC-MD5 HMAC-SHA1 HMAC-SHA224 HMAC-SHA256 HMAC-SHA384 HMAC-SHA512
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.996 TKEY mode 2 support (Diffie-Hellman): yes
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.996 TKEY mode 3 support (GSS-API): yes
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.996 config.c: option 'trust-anchor-telemetry' is experimental and subject to change in the future
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.996 loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.996 open: /etc/bind/named.conf: file not found
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.996 loading configuration: file not found
29-Dec-2023 07:40:31.996 exiting (due to fatal error)
```

Если я из запуска контейнера уберу ***-v /var/test/bind:/etc/bind*** то контейнер запускается без проблем и всё работает хорошо.

Вопрос что я делаю не так?

Comment: 1) А что вообще делает `COPY` с тремя файлами (хорошо - двумя файлами и каталогом)? Я думал только источник и приёмник можно указать. 2) Что у вас в `/var/test/bind`, есть ли там `named.conf`?

Comment: 1) COPY копирует три файла с настройками для работы DNS с моим доменом. 2) /var/test/bind создается вмести с созданием контейнера или мне сначала нужно создать /var/test/bind с файлами и потом уже создавать контейнер?

Comment: Содержимое `/var/test/bind` подставляется вместо `/etc/bind` из образа. Поэтому если в `/var/test/bind` нет `named.conf`, то и взяться ему неоткуда.

Comment: А возможно ли из контейнера содержимое сохранить на хост-машине при создании контейнера?

Comment: CrazyElf и PakUula спасибо Вам за помощь. Я наконец то разобрался как работает docker думаю вопросы ещё определенно появятся но в целом теперь всё встало на своё место. Данные из контейнера на хост скопировал

Comment: @Mister_X Хорошо было бы, если бы вы добавили свой ответ с подробностями, как вы решили вашу проблему. Я за него проголосую.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу хочу сказать еще раз спасибо CrazyElf и PakUula за помощь.

Решил свой вопрос следующим образом сначала запустил создал контейнер без volumes и скопировал с контейнера на хост все файлы из /etc/bind командой

```
docker cp test1:/etc/bind  /var/test/bind
```

Далее остановил и удалил контейнер и переписал точнее удалил лишнее в самом images и привел его к такому виду:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y bind9

CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-g", "-c", "/etc/bind/named.conf", "-u", "bind"]

EXPOSE 53/tcp
EXPOSE 53/udp
EXPOSE 953/tcp
```

и создал контейнер уже с указанием тома в который копировал файлы с контейнера.